# Visual Studio 2013 Azure Publish profile same Azure account but different developers

Tags: azure, tfs, visual-studio-2013

Let's say I have an Azure website with an Azure online account (user/pwd), and from the Azure panel, I've downloaded the Visual Studio Publish profile file (.PublishSettings).
Then we import the file in the Visual Studio Publish screen and I can deploy to Azure fine and I check in my changes in TFS which includes the files .pubxml. All good.

However, a second developer get latest version, he has the publish profiles files, but when he tries to Publish to azure, doesn't work. The error says something like the user or password is not right, however is the same file that I used to publish and worked fine.
Then what he does is to import again the same Azure profile file that I did, and VS creates a second "Web deploy 2.pubxml" file, then he tries to publish, and works.
If I try to publish with the new WebDeploy 2 file, I cannot, so it seems that something is specific of the local machine that makes that I only can use the publish profile file that I imported, and my teammate, the one which He imported, even the Azure account is exactly same user-pwd and same Azure website URL.

Is there a way to avoid this? because in a large team, that means a lot of different Publish profile files when actually, the azure account is the same one.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Giving every member on a large team the ability to publish to the cloud using a shared login..... what could possibly go wrong?

Comment: really helpful... it's the same problem with 20 devs that with just 2, VS seems that need a specific file for each, even the Azure data is the same. Do you know how to fix it???

Comment: In a way you got my point.  I don't use practices that don't scale to hundreds of developers.  Look for a proper release management strategy.  For Azure that might mean something like http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/release-management-vs.aspx

Comment: I'm totally curious, could you explain how you work with 100 devs? Do you have 100 azure accounts and 100 VS publishing profile files? Thanks for the link.

Comment: You should look at using TFS builds to perform continuous deployment.  Checkin to TFS can trigger a publish - that way you don't need to share any Azure logins.

Comment: it's an option, but in my case, we don't want to publish to azure in any check in. I'm wondering if we can publish to azure from the command line or power-shell, maybe could be another option. Many thanks.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I'm having the same problem and i don't want one publish profile per deployer + one for each envinronment.

Comment: I wasn't :( what we are doing is having a specific folder in TFS foreach user, and then we are playing with the Maps and the Cloak option to make that every user is mapped with their specific publishing profile. But you still have one file per each user in a TFS folder, the only difference is that you only see your file in Visual Studio. Hope it helps...

Comment: Just to add to this, I am a developer who works from home about as much as I do from the office. I have to manually enter passwords if I'm not on the computer I created the publish profile from. I suspect (though I have not seen docs to confirm) that the password is saved using DPAPI, which is specific to the machine in question, hence my project files which are replicated to my home computer using OneDrive cannot access the stored password from my work computer. I'm also pretty certain there's no way around this.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'm pretty sure of that too. BTW, with VS 2013 SP1 (or some update, not sure), the project template now adds some PowerShell scripts to publish to Azure. I've not used them yet, but could be an option to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

The 2nd developer needs to manually enter the encrypted password into the appropriate profile by copying the value from the `'userPWD="xxxxx"'` attribute from the publish profile xml file.

I'm in a team of 2 developers and have the same problem.  Careful not to touch any other settings, as 2nd developers copy of the profile will be saved for check-in.

Comment: @Opal This _is_ an answer to the question. Did you read it or did you just react to the "[I] have the same problem" part?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the Connection tab after you open the Publish dialog? When you check-in to source control, the password is not saved in the .pubxml file. The second developer can get the password from the PublishSettings file and put that into Publish dialog, then it should work.

Comment: I'll check it again, but when I saw this behaviour, that was one of the first things I tried, but I got an auth error, even all the data was right (url, user, pwd...). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Went to the Azure portal, downloaded the publishing profile from the portal, opened it, copied the encoded (hashed) password from the pubxml file, and pasted it in the password prompt message box (not in the local pubxml file, but rather in the password entry in the message box displayed while trying to publish).

Strangely, it worked.